# sort data for an undefined range, using values in the first column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

i am trying to sort data in a worksheet using the first column as the sorting criteria which contains the employee id. The below code is what i've tried, it works but as you can see it is for a limited range("A2:F7"). Now i can change the first column selection using excel down, but i am clueless how to do it for the entire range.
Would shift + ctrl + end or another variation of it work ?

```
' Sort Data According to emp_id
                    '
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp Calc").Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp Calc").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A7" _
                    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp Calc").Sort
                        .SetRange Range("A1:F7")
                        .Header = xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                        .Apply
                    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
.SetRange Range("A1:F7", Range("A1:F7").End(xlDown))
```